# How can I use PHP to connect to ODBC to DB2 on Windows 2003?

Tags: php, linux, db2, odbc

My old server:
- Windows 2003 Server
- IBM DB2 UDB Version 8.1
- ODBC: User DSN:

[image: My ODBC Connection]

There is a .NET webapps connect to MYDB using ODBC, it is good now.

But Windows 2003 is end of support from Microsoft on this month. So, I want to move from it.

The problem: I don't know .NET at all. The current .NET webapps was closed source and I cannot contact to provider company (it was defunct).

I want to get all tables from DB2 from PHP (running in my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop). I like to use PDO ODBC to connect. But it seems to be over my skills. My desktop is on the same subnet LAN with Windows 2003 server (ping to and from is OK), telnet server2003 ip port 5000 is OK.

I am stuck after install ODBC, config something in my desktop... Nothing works.

Who helps me? Every help is appreciated. There are no words to show my appreciation!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to configuring and troubleshooting PHP access to DB2 via PDO ODBC, you will also need to migrate your DB2 8.1 server and clients, if any, to a newer DB2 release level (IBM [ended support](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=71&uid=swg21370360) for DB2 UDB 8.1 back in May 2009). Fortunately, IBM now offers a no-cost version of DB2 called [Express-C](http://www.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express-c/), which is authorized for production use. The current release, DB2 Express-C 10.5 Fix Pack 5, can accommodate databases up to 15 terabytes in size.

If it turns out that your company has an active DB2 license available for your application, then forget about Express-C and install whatever DB2 server edition is covered by your license.

To move your data out of DB2 UDB 8.1, you'll need to export the contents of each table to a separate file and import them into the new database. The [db2move](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_8.2.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/r0002079.htm) utility can assist with this process by iterating through all the tables in your database, saving you from typing all those [EXPORT](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_8.2.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/r0008303.htm) statements yourself.

Once your DB2 data is migrated to a new database, you can install a DB2 client on your Linux PHP server and test your connectivity. To keep the file size down, IBM offers a variety of DB2 client downloads, which can add some confusion as to which one you need. For ODBC and PHP applications, you should download the IBM Data Server Driver Package or, to be safe, the larger IBM Data Server Client which contains all the drivers and client libraries. Be sure that the client you download is the same version and Fix Pack level as your DB2 server (e.g. 10.5 Fix Pack 5).

IBM's online [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.php.doc/doc/t0023135.html) and the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-ibm.php) have a bit of information about connecting PHP applications to DB2.

Comment: Very good information. Thanks for your advice! In the process, if I have questions, will I ask you?

Comment: You can post additional questions here, but there are also good online communities for DB2 on IDUG.org and the IBM DB2 Express-C Forum on the IBM developerWorks site.